# Drag and drop in XUL

Tags: javascript, html, listbox, xul

How can I allow drag and drop on the listbox items to rearrange the items in XUL? I'm doing this in a firefox addon. I've tried `draggable="true"` in the listbox tag but that doesn't seem to have worked. Could you provide some example XUL listbox code where drag and drop would work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have also included [ondragstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#Starting_a_Drag_Operation) after draggable was set and then the other [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#Finishing_a_Drag) attributes for the drop.